# How Can I Create A Camera Follow Similar To Mario But Vertical?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, 2d

I'm attempting to write a camera follow script for my vertical platformer game, I've viewed many tutorials and have found a few that work to a degree but not exactly what I need.

I essentially want to create the same logic that Mario games use when deciding the camera must follow the player and when not to, but in the Y Axis instead, below is an example from the Mario games:

[image]

Below is what I've attempted, I receive no errors but still the camera remains stationary (it doesn't do anything), and cameraLeadingUp and CameraLeadingDown never become true in the inspector.

```
void Start()
    {
        camHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize;

        camWidth = camHeight * Camera.main.aspect;

        cameraLeadingUp = true;

        cameraLeadingDown = false;
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {

        Vector3 temp = transform.position;

        if (cameraLeadingUp)
        {
            if (playerLocation.position.y < camHeight / 0.25f)
            {
                cameraLeadingDown = true;
                cameraLeadingUp = false;
            }
        }
        else if (cameraLeadingDown)
        {
            if (playerLocation.position.y > camHeight / 0.25f)
            {
                cameraLeadingUp = true;
                cameraLeadingDown = false;
            }
        }

        if (cameraLeadingDown)
        {
            temp.y = Mathf.Min(camHeight / 0.90f, playerLocation.position.y);
        }

        if (cameraLeadingUp)
        {
            temp.y = Mathf.Max(camHeight / 0.90f, playerLocation.position.y);
        }

        transform.position = temp;
    }
```

Comment: You set `cameraLeadingUp = false;` and `cameraLeadingUp = true;` but there is **no** way any of them can ever be true without the other one being true first

Comment: Thank you @CamiloTerevinto, that makes sense, I'm unsure what to do to fix it though, any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion : Don't use `Update` use `FixedUpdate`(Physics based) which will give you more smooth camera follow.

Comment: Alright so I've now edited the above code and it seems to be doing what I'm trying to achieve, but backwards. It is keeping my player center of the screen unless he reaches the bounds and then the camera stops, what I need is the opposite where the camera remains stationary unless the player moves outside of the bounds

Comment: What is the value of camheigh ?